# GCP hosted Wordpress Site - ERR_TIMED_OUT

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

I am new to this forum and am after some assistance. My wordpress website has been hosted on GCP since 2019 and I have never had an issue.

I was on the site yesterday making notes of some adjustments I want to make to it, go to access today and I get an `ERR_TIMED_OUT` error.

I have tried on a couple of devices and get the same message.
[image: see image attached]

Everything is on - but the CPU usage for the compute engine is really low...

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at logs? Timeout generally means a script is taking too long to output anything. Can be errors, loops, server configurations. Just make sure error logging is turned on everywhere, and they are not suppressed.

Comment: Can you SSH into the VM instance and look for logs?

Comment: Serhii - I can SSH into the VM. Just dont know how to look for logs... embarassing for an IT person isnt it :)

Comment: If your site has been running for a while and now fails, start with these items. 1) Did the external public IP address change? 2) Has the instance ran out of free disk space?

Comment: I think it was a combination of all of the above. Working again! Thanks